# Adding values to a BIRT report through servlet

Tags: java, pdf, servlets, jakarta-ee, birt

Please before you say its repeated please understand my problem.

Im developing Java EE 8 application which makes use of BIRT to generate a pdf and send it on to client. I've already completed report design, and webpages to take the data, and also servlets to process render and send the generated pdf(generic).

But i want to add the data received from the request directly to the generated pdf ie without adding them to a database(so i cannot add the values by binding data source).Ive even added the names in report design to enable me to add values at run time.

Ive seen [How do you set and pass a parameter to a BIRT report created by the BIRT Report Designer through the BIRT API?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10747427/how-do-you-set-and-pass-a-parameter-to-a-birt-report-created-by-the-birt-report) and understood idea there but my problem is i have date columns in my design which has to be set as well.

What im hoping with this question is

1. A simple example to the provided solution in the linked post.Or a
   better solution if present.
2. Which is the class which can populate the BIRT-date since java.util.Date is deprecated.
3. And to know if BIRT api  provides way to manuplate the report elements via name or id in a servlet or a model java class.

thankyou for your help
forgiving me if i have bored you with a long question.

Ashwin

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why don't you just consider using a string representation of the date values instead?

Comment: I can do that thank you... ill try that .. thank you for ur idea